# UILabel, UITextField, UITextView の違いは何ですか？

Tags: ios, objective-c

- UILabel
- UITextField
- UITextView

この３つの違いはなんですか？

Comment: すでに同様の質問がありました。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040409/uilabel-uitextfield-uitextview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

・UILabel
　表示専用

・UITextField
　キーボードによる入力が可能

・UITextView
　キーボードによる入力が可能
　複数行可